# How to upload image to keystone

Tags: react-native, graphql, cloudinary

Here I am using cloudinary when i click photo and upload using apollo upload it says invalid value can anyone suggest how to post
[Cloudinary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FuIK.jpg)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please share details of the API call (request) you're making and exact response you're receiving.